# empty cells check in rule-engine decision tables

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, kie-server

I want to create a `decision table` with some empty cells.

the auto-generated rule is like this.

```
rule "Row 1 some name"
enabled false
salience -99
no-loop true
dialect "mvel"
when
    $p : Model1( name == "string" )
    $output : Model2( model3Code== ( $a.code ), model1Code== ( $p.code) )
then
    $output.setSomeProperty( false );
end
```

In the above code, you see because of column3 is empty `$a` not generated, and the build of rules failed.

My problem is to know how I can check if a cell is empty or not and empty cells ignore from `Model2` conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a solution for this.

If in the `Model2` condition select type of condition to `predicate` and use `$param` inside it, when the cell is empty that condition not added to rule anymore. Only conditions that it's `$param" parameters are set will be generated.

Comment: It would be nice to see the code